Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook for MS outlook 2021
I have a windows application for sending emails using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook. (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook --version 15.0.4797.1004).
it was working fine till date. now the user upgraded the MS outlook from 2019 to outlook 2021.
now my application is not working. When we try to send email it shows error "Unable to cast COM object Type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass to interface type". I cannot find updated version of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook dll. Please advise how can we resolve this. Thank you
I stopped working on Dotnet for 3 years and shifted to other technology. but still need to support this application. and not sure what is the updated method to resolve Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook issue for MS outook 2021.

Show us your actual code. Have you first checked to see if it's a simple x64/x86 issue?

Hi. there is no error in code.. I tried to use this dll.
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;  user install the set up file and tried to send email from the application. then we got this error.   Unable to cast com object of type Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Applicationclass interface.   Please advise how to check x64 / x86 issue?
